# What is causing the output image of this ffmpeg command to reduce by~95% in file size?

Tags: ffmpeg, jpeg

```
ffmpeg -i FName1.jpg -i FName2.jpg -filter_complex hstack outputH.jpg
```

I've two jpg photos files, and the above is used to combine them into one jpg file. The image size is as expected - same vertical dimension & double the horizontal, but the file size reduces by about ~95%. What's causing it & is there a way to prevent it?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the images.

Comment: Why would that help?

Comment: Firstly it would ensure your question is an [mcve] and secondly it would be possible to analyse the parameters of your input and output images and see where/how they differ. Don't forget that compressibility of an image, and therefore size, is partially dependent on image content.

Comment: My question is not a duplicate of the one in the link given. No searching of this site for a solution using appropriate keywords returns that post, indeed it's not listed in the 'related questions' below.  It does however contain /a/ solution to the question and should have been posted as such. The question should have been left open so I could assess that & other possible answers and accept the best one. V. sad that a valid Q has been down voted.

Comment: Equally sad that you didn't originally post a proper [mcve] in line with SO guidelines, nor follow my suggestion that you add your images.

Comment: I think I provided the relevant information as stated in that link. Is there not a upload limit of ~2mb for this site?